# Changing disabled button style conditionally

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

In my react-native app i have a disabled button that should be enabled after selecting buttons from the same screen, it's working fine but i have a problem with it's style, it should be changed if it's enabled or disabled but it's not, here is my code:

```
 isSubmitButtonDisabled = () => {
    return !this.state.selected;
   }

<Button disabled={this.isSubmitButtonDisabled()} style={isSubmitButtonDisabled() ? disabledStyle : enabledStyle}>
   <Text style={isSubmitButtonDisabled() ? disabledStyle : enabledStyle}>Submit</Text>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `this.`:

Replace `isSubmitButtonDisabled() ? disabledStyle : enabledStyle` with: `this.isSubmitButtonDisabled() ? disabledStyle : enabledStyle`